# How to call a webservice in spring from the jersey client program

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey-1.0

I have written the client program using the jersey framework but my webservice is of different project which uses spring framework. So I want to write the webservice using spring . When I wrote it something is going wrong .The webservice is not getting called.
Here is my code
ModelerServiceClient.java is written using jersey

ModelerServiceClient.java

```
package com.tcs.DataShare.Client;
import java.io.File;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
//import com.tcs.srl.smart.utility.PropertyReader;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.utils.ProductConfiguration;
public class ModelerServiceClient {
    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DataShareServiceClient.class);

    private WebResource service;
    private ClientResponse response;
    private String serviceName;
    private String vmAddress;
    private String portNumber;
    private String WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE;
    public ModelerServiceClient() {
        try {
            serviceName = "BPIngestorAppaaS";
            vmAddress = ProductConfiguration
                    .getStringValueForProductProperty("vmAddress");
            portNumber = ProductConfiguration
                    .getStringValueForProductProperty("portNumber");
            System.out
                    .println("vm address:" + vmAddress + "port:" + portNumber);
            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE = ProductConfiguration
                    .getStringValueForProductProperty("WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE");

            service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
                    "http://" + vmAddress + ":" + portNumber + "/"
                            + WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE).build());
            System.out.println("war name is: "+WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE);
            System.out.println("URL is: "+service);
        } catch (NullPointerException nullex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured - " + nullex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("" + ex);
        }
    }
    public ModelerServiceClient(String localhost, String port,
            String serviceName) {
        this.vmAddress = localhost;
        this.portNumber = port;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        System.out.println("vm address:" + vmAddress + "port:" + portNumber);
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE = ProductConfiguration
                .getStringValueForProductProperty("WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE");

        service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://" + vmAddress + ":" + portNumber + "/" + WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE)
                .build());
        LOGGER.debug("WAR_FILE_NAME in the client program"+WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE);
        System.out.println("In the data share constructor"+WAR_FILE_NAME_DATASHARE);
        System.out.println("service is" + service);
    }
    public HashMap createTable(String folderToBeZipped) {

        LOGGER.debug("DataShareServiceClient :: zipFolder() : Calling zipFolderWithSubsequestFolder Service -> folderToBeZipped: "
                + folderToBeZipped);
        HashMap map=new HashMap();
        LOGGER.debug("before webservice ");
        System.out.println("in the create table method in modelerServiceClient class");
        response = service.path("dataModeler").path("ModelerService")
                .path("createTablesFromEntity")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, folderToBeZipped);
        System.out.println("After calling response,in the create table method in modelerServiceClient class");
        LOGGER.debug("INSIDE THE ZIP METHOD FOR CHECKING ZIP METHOD");
        LOGGER.debug("after webservice ");
    //  InputStream inputStream = response.getEntityInputStream();


        LOGGER.debug("DataShareServiceClient :: createTable() : Calling createTable() Service done");
        return map;
    }
}
```

DataShareCentralController.java is in spring

DataShareCentralController.java

```
package com.tcs.ngps.sip.restservices.controllers;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobKey;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.tcs.ngps.sip.model.ModelerResponse;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.Services.DataIngestionServices;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.constants.IngesterConstants;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.constants.ModelerConstants;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.enumeration.TechnologyServices;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.ingester.CreateTableUsingEntityJson;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.tracker.StatusActivityTracker;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.modeler.utils.Utilities;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.restservices.viewmodels.AnalysisInputModel;
//import com.tcs.ngps.sip.Services.CIServices;
/*
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.Services.SearchServices;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.commonUtitlities.CommonUtilities;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.constants.RequestConstants;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.model.RequestModel;
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.model.ResponceModel;
 */
import com.tcs.ngps.sip.restservices.viewmodels.ResponseModel;
//@Path("/ModelerService")
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class DataShareCentralController {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ModelerCentralController.class);

    DataShareCentralController()
    {
        System.out.println("In the DataShareCentralController ");
    }
//  @Path("/createTablesFromEntity")
    //@POST
    //@Produces("application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/ModelerService/createTablesFromEntity", method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void CreateTableFromEntity(@Context HttpServletRequest requestObj,String serviceData )
    {
        System.out.println("done dana done");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            System.out.println("in the controller");
            JSONObject serviceJSON = (JSONObject) parser.parse(serviceData);
            String datashareURL = (String) serviceJSON
                    .get(ModelerConstants.DATASHARE_URL);

            CreateTableUsingEntityJson createTableUsingEntityJson=new CreateTableUsingEntityJson();
        createTableUsingEntityJson.getData();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me in resolving the issue....

Comment: What do you mean "not getting called"? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Also can you show where you actually create the `ModelServiceClient` and call it's `createTable` method.

Comment: I am not getting any exception . but the print statement present in the CreateTableFromEntity() is not getting printed as well as whatever present in the getData () is not executing.   I have one webservice ConfigureAndrew written using jersey. in that I am creating object of ModelerServiceClient  and calling it's method

Comment: Also your Spring method is for `GET` requests, and the client is trying to make a POST request (`.post(ClientResponse.class, folderToBeZipped);)`

Comment: Also maybe you should print out some results from the response. You currently don't do anything with it. Maybe there are some details in the response object

Comment: Thanks for your help.That problem is solved when I changed get request to post. But now the problem is in the class DataShareCentralController.java in method  public void CreateTableFromEntity(@Context HttpServletRequest requestObj,String serviceData ) I am getting value of parameter serviceData as null.

Comment: Add `@RequestBody` to the `String serviceData` and see what happens